# Taking Log Transformation of unit circle using Presentations package

Tags: plotting, commercial-package

```
<< Presentations`

circle = ComplexCircle[0.1, 1/2];
domain = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 2,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> z, ImageSize -> 200];
image = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle // ComplexMap[Log]},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 4,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> w,
   ImageSize -> 200];
Row[{domain, image}]
```

The above code works, creating the following image.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, if I change the center to the origin:

```
circle = ComplexCircle[0, 1/2];
domain = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 2,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> z, ImageSize -> 200];
image = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle // ComplexMap[Log]},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 4,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> w,
   ImageSize -> 200];
Row[{domain, image}]
```

The code fails, giving the following error message:

> Coordinate {DirectedInfinity[-1], 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

But this works with center at the origin:

```
circle = {Red, Thickness[0.02], 
   ComplexCurve[Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]};
domain = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 2,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> z, ImageSize -> 200];
image = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], circle // ComplexMap[Log]},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRange -> 4,
   FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
   PlotLabel -> w,
   ImageSize -> 200];
Row[{domain, image}]
```

Producing this image:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's going on?

Comment: I think it is this. In the circle case, the ComplexMap[Log] takes Log of the center, Log of the radius, and just draws another circle with the results. Hence, Log[0] is the problem?